# Google maps javascript API "geolocation service failed" in server but works on local

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3, ngrok

So I set up a ngrok temporary server to show my employer how her website is looking but then noticed that google map's Javascript API fails while on ngrok, while on my localhost it's working, is this some quirk with ngrok or will it happen when we start hosting it on a real server?
I have the geolocation on /scripts/js/geolocation.js and the page that is calling it is on /orders.php

geolocation.js:

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 6
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        });
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}
```

orders.php:

```
<div id="map">
    <script>initMap()</script>
</div>


<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=REDACTED&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Localhost:
[image: Local:]

Ngrok:
[image: Ngrok]

Comment: Have you taken a look in console? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I would also suggest you remove your API key from StackOverflow just in case someone decides to use it for evil.

Comment: Perhaps, supplying the `options` argument to `geolocation.getCurrentPosition` with suitable values might help improve the results - also using the `watchPosition` method might be of use too

Comment: @AwPa thank you I completely forgot. I do get a error message in the console but it happens in both localhost and ngrok Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at initMap (geolocation.js:2)
    at orders.php:43

Comment: I am not sure if that is the reason, but have you activated google maps javascript api in your google developer's account?

Comment: @AwPa yes, I had problems with that as well because I didn't in the beggining but that gives a specific error in the console warning about that.

Comment: i think the problem is that your google api key is restricted only to your localhost domain, can you verify allowed domains in your developer account, and add the domain you are using with ngrok

Comment: @HaythemROUIS it has no restrictions, but I also don't pay for it, this is the free version of the API, think that can be a problem?

Comment: Another debugging idea is to replace the error function function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }) with something along these lines function(error){console.log(error)}. Might give you more insights into what is wrong.

Comment: @RamRaider Sorry I'm new to the geolocation API, what should I place in the options?

Comment: No, by default there are no restrictions to the API as far as I know. You can restrict it to protect your API key from being used by unauthorized domains

Comment: @AwPa the error returned : Only secure origins are allowed (see: REDACTED, stackoverflow doesn't allow URL shorteners)., So it's because the server is not in HTTPS, is there any way to make it ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference of someone that might need help with this aswell:

Question solved with the help of  @AwPa, @RamRaider, @HaythamROUIS.
So the problem was that the server was in http instead of https, the only thing you need to do is (if you are using ngrok) place https:// in the beginning of the url since ngrok hosts both http and https at the same time, or change your webserver's configuration to use HTTPS.

https link on ngrok:
[image: ngrok]

**Important Note:** Like @RamRaider said, use , do this with everything you fetch using URL's, it's better not to hardcode the protocol that will be used, doing it this way will use the protocol that is currently being used on the website, in this case https.

Comment: You might find it helpful to use `<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps...` without the protocol so the remote resource is then loaded with the current protocol on local server for the page in question

Comment: @RamRaider thank you, I'll add that to my code and I'll add it to the answer as well.